# Pulumi: How to restore accidentally deleted state file stored in Azure Storage Account

Tags: pulumi

Is there a way to restore accidentally deleted stacks/state files from backups or histories stored in Azure Storage Account?

[image]

Comment: If you go to the `stacks` directory you should have `.bak` file with the same name of your deleted stack